# Check if lat/lon in polygon (R)

Tags: r, r-sf, r-sp

I have a lat/lon combination and want to check whether the point is inside a polygon (`sp::Polygon` class)

Consider this example:

```
UKJ32 <- sp::Polygon(cbind(c(-1.477037449999955, -1.366895449999959, -1.365159449999965, -1.477037449999955),
                           c(50.923958250000027, 50.94686525000003, 50.880069750000018, 50.923958250000027))) %>%
   list() %>% 
   sp::Polygons(ID="UKJ32 - Southampton")
```

I would now like to test whether the points in `df` are in this polygon (and if so, return the Polygon ID).

```
tibble(lon = c(-1.4, 10), lat = c(50.9, 10))
```

Can someone tell me how I get to the result

```
tibble(lon = c(-1.4, 10), lat = c(50.9, 10), polyg_ID = 'UKJ32')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to stick to `sp`, there is a `point.in.polygon()` function in `sp` package:

```r
UKJ32 <- sp::Polygon(cbind(c(-1.477037449999955, -1.366895449999959, -1.365159449999965, -1.477037449999955),
                           c(50.923958250000027, 50.94686525000003, 50.880069750000018, 50.923958250000027))) |>
  list() |>
  sp::Polygons(ID="UKJ32 - Southampton")

a <- tibble::tibble(lon = c(-1.4, 10), lat = c(50.9, 10))

sp::point.in.polygon(a$lon, a$lat, UKJ32@Polygons[[1]]@coords[,1], UKJ32@Polygons[[1]]@coords[,2])
#> [1] 1 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It doesn't _have_ to be `sp`, I'm also open to other solutions if they're better suitable

Comment: Have a look on st_join(), st_intersects(), st_within() functions from `sf` package.

Answer (score 2):

The `{sp}` package is by now somewhat dated - after having lived a long & fruitful life - and most of current action happens in context of its successor, the `{sf}` package.

Assigning some kind of a polygon feature - either an id or a metric - to a points dataset is a frequent use case. It at present often  done via a `sf::st_join()` call. For an example in action consider this earlier answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64704624/7756889

I suggest that you try to move your workflow to the more current `{sf}` package; you will find it easier to keep up with recent development.

And even if this were not possible for whatever reason - use  `sp::Polygons()` with utmost caution. I carries no information about coordinate reference system - which is a fancy way of saying it has no way of interpreting the coordinate numbers. Are they decimal degrees, or meters? Could be feet or fathoms for all that I know.

Strictly speaking you should *not* be allowed to proceed with a point-in-polygon operation calculation without this information.

Comment: Wouldn't `sf::st_contains(polygon, point)` be an even more elegant solution here?

Comment: `sf::st_contains()` will return index of the polygon containing the point; definitely a step in the right direction. On the other hand `st_join(points, polygons)` will return the points objects, enriched for all non-geometry columns of the polygons object - such as the polygon ID requested by OP in his example of a desired tibble. So really depends on what the use case is...

Comment: Oh, must have missed that, my bad. Nevermind then. Yeah, this totally depends on the desired output - check for topological relations vs. actual resulting objects based on said relation.