# How to count the number of observations within EEZ of Japan from latitude and longitude data in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a dataframe that shows the count of fishing operations along with their latitude and longitude information. My goal is to sum the count of operations within the Exclusive Economic Zone (EEZ) of Japan.

```
# create a sample dataset 
latitude <- c(37, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 33)
latitude_m <- c(14, 40, 42, 43, 42, 58, 45, 34, 16, 31)
longitude <- c(150, 155, 157, 140, 145, 147, 140, 125, 137, 144)
longitude_m <- c(18, 4, 7, 2, 57, 19, 5, 3, 35, 55)
ope_nums <- 1:10
df1 <- data.frame(latitude, latitude_m, longitude, longitude_m, ope_nums)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(longitude = longitude + longitude_m/60) %>% 
  mutate(latitude = latitude + latitude_m/60) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), 
               crs = 4326, na.fail = F)
```

I followed [this instruction](https://rpubs.com/drfinlayscott/989660) on how to load the EEZ of Japan and created a polygon map with my fishing operation data overlayed. I know what I should do here is to determine if each operation is within the EEZ based on its latitude and longitude, and then aggregate the data. However, I am unable to figure out how to do this. Can anybody help with this?

```
# read Japanese EEZ data
eez <- sf::st_read("World_EEZ_v11_20191118_HR_0_360", 
                   layer="eez_v11_0_360")
eez_JP <- eez %>% 
  filter(GEONAME == "Japanese Exclusive Economic Zone")

eez_JP %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = df2, size = 1, color = "#f14d41")
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying if a spatial point is in a spatial polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64680668/identifying-if-a-spatial-point-is-in-a-spatial-polygon)

Comment: The operation you describe is a problem often called point in polygon operation; it has several possible solutions in R. I would recommend `sf::st_join()` between polygon and points object; for its example in action consider the answer linked above.

Comment: @JindraLacko, Thank you for your comment! This helped me solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Update

I tried point in polygon operation according to the advice from Jindra Lacko and [this article](https://mattherman.info/blog/point-in-poly/), which led me to solve the issue with the code below.

```
# points-in-polygon operation
df2_in_eezJP <- st_join(df2, eez_JP, join = st_within)

as_tibble(df2_in_eezJP) %>% 
  group_by(GEONAME) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(ope_nums))

# check with mapping
eez_JP %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = df2, size = 1, color = "#f14d41")
```